# Checkbox is checked show button

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I want to show a Next button once my checkbox is checked. Below is my jquery code for the checkbox. Once the checkbox is checked the Next button should shows up and the Submit button should hide. If the checkbox is not checked, only the Submit button will be shown. I have created the code accordingly but i dont know why the program is not running as it should.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkrecc" ><label>Check this</label>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

     var $submit = $("#indrecc").hide(),
     $cbs = $('input[name="checkrecc"]').click(function() {
     $submit.toggle( $cbs.is(":checked") );
     });

     });
</script>
<br>
<input type="nextstep" id="indrecc" value="Next" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
<input type="submit" name="indsubmit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="margin-bottom: 5px;">
```

Comment: Define *program is not running as it should*. Errors?

Comment: @IonicãBizãu actually no errors just when i click on the checkbox the Next button is not showing up

Comment: Here is a fiddle, and apart from the input type being 'nextstep', it seems to work ? http://jsfiddle.net/Agm8g/

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov still its not working in my program

Comment: Any messages in your dev console ? Did you load jquery ? It's really hard to tell ...

Comment: @DimitarDimitrov thanks a lot because of my carelessness i forget to load my jquery. Now it works

Comment: Yeah, don't worry, it happens :)

Answer (score 1):

And the problem with your HTML is `type="nextstep"`, there is no such input type. HTML assign default `text` type to it.

```
<input type="nextstep" id="indrecc" value="Next" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
         //^ type="button"
```

Change it to :

```
<input type="button" id="indrecc" value="Next" class="btn btn-info btn-block" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
```

You need to toggle submit button along with the `next` element.

This should work for you.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $submit = $("#indrecc").hide(),
        $cbs = $('input[name="checkrecc"]').click(function () {
            $submit.toggle($cbs.is(":checked"));
            $('[name=indsubmit]').toggle(!$cbs.is(":checked"));
        });

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9P84w/1/)**

Comment: this is how i want it to work but once i add in my program the my Next button is showing up before the checkbox is checked

Comment: You need to hide it on `document.ready` check whether the `hide()` code really works.